# How do I filter choices from a lookup field that points to a different SharePoint list?

Tags: filtering, powerapps, lookupfield

I have an app built based on the a SharePoint list called "Proposal Tracker". One of the fields is a lookup field that provides a drop down from another list called "Employees". I am trying to filter this field, so that when I select it, the only employee names that are shown are the "active" employees.

I've tried adding this into the `DataField` of the one data card I'm trying to filter, but I get an error.

```
Filter(Employees,Status.Value = "Active")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Filter(CollectionName,Condition)

e.g: Filter(Employees,Status = "Active")

Answer (score 0):

When you have a dropdown control selected you can choose its dependencies from other controls on the screen.

Example:

[image: PowerApps screenshot]